# Does the sentry's Guardian Shield protect units from ranged attacks if the attackers are inside the shield?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

Let's say army A has 5 stalkers and army B has 5 stalkers and a [sentry](http://sc2armory.com/game/protoss/units/sentry).

If the [sentry](http://sc2armory.com/game/protoss/units/sentry) is in the middle of army B and throws up [a guardian shield](http://sc2armory.com/game/protoss/units/sentry) while army A is still well outside the radius of the shield, obviously army B will take reduced damage from A's ranged attacks.

If the A stalkers sacrifice the time and health to walk inside of the guardian shield, literally standing right next to B's stalkers, are their attacks still reduced by the sentry's shield?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Guardian shield confers the damage reduction to all friendly unit inside its radius, regardless of the location of the source inflicting the damage. It doesn't matter if the enemy is inside or outside the shield.

**EDIT:** some ranged units (specifically hydralisks and roaches) have an alternate attack animation when they are in melee range. This attack does not count as a ranged attack - so it is not affected by guardian shield or point-defense drones. Moving these units into close proximity with the units defended by the guardian shield can be beneficial, then, but again it has nothing to do with whether the attacker is actually inside the guardian shield or not.

Comment: Good catch on hydra/roach.  This is some discussion that this is a bug and eventually Blizzard will fix it, but no official word thus far.

Comment: wow!  i am not crazy then.  i could swear i saw a roach swat at a target with his front leg.  now i want to go see what a hydra does.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know for the 2nd attack, thanks

Comment: hydra slashes with his two front "scythes" or stabs down with them