# Which upgrade do hydralisks/roaches use when meleeing?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

In similar vein to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6976/what-attack-upgrade-do-starcraft-2s-roaches-use) and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6989/what-attack-upgrade-do-banelings-use):

Hydralisks and roaches have a special melee animation when the enemy is within melee-range.  I thought this was just for show, and I've actually heard speculation that it's a bug, but Oak recently mentioned that this attack shares some of the other benefits of melee-attacks (namely, [not being affected by the guardian's shield](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5637/does-the-sentrys-guardian-shield-protect-units-from-ranged-attacks-if-the-attack/5639#5639)).

However, I wouldn't think their attack would be affected by melee-upgrade, since there is no listing for it on the unit-card.  So which is it? *(references please, I'm not looking for speculation)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They use the ranged upgrade.

If you open up the galaxy editor and look at the Hydralisk/Roach you'll notice that they have two different weapons: one for range, one for melee.  You'll notice that both of these attacks have the same upgrade specified.

Here we see the relationship between `Zerg Missile Attacks` and `Hydralisk Melee`

[image]

If select `Zerg Missile Attacks` and select `Upgrade Effects+` we can see where the association is set

[image]

Comment: The sc2armory.com pages for [Roaches](http://sc2armory.com/game/zerg/units/roach) and [Hydralisks](http://sc2armory.com/game/zerg/units/hydralisk), while less definitive, also show that they only have one attack, and that it uses the ranged upgrade.

Comment: I know blizzard at one point says "there is no difference only animation," but that was disproven by guardian shield.

Comment: this sucks. they should use the melee upgrades when in melee combat

Comment: @john some how using two different upgrades for one units' attack feels a little like penalizing Zerg

Comment: yeah but it also means that if you upgrade melee for zerglings then you have it for Hydras and Roaches too ;)